# Debug worker project run as a process from another project in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

I have two projects. One of them is a worker application that does some stuff. The other one is a GUI for the worker (GUI runs async processes that are instances of a worker). So the worker project output is an `.exe` file that is used by a GUI.

How to debug the worker? Is there any possibility of doing it? The annoying thing is I can create a command line interface for a worker and generate some kind of reference params for it to run it separatelly, but the problem is when I want to do this for more than one instance (I have a program that generates some data async so I have to find an error in my code which works fine in one process, but buggy in more than one).

Comment: Can't you just attach the debugger to the worker process?

Comment: How to do this? Could you point me in some way?

Comment: in VS, Ctrl-Alt-P or Debug->Attach to Process

Comment: I don't understand. What should I attach to? My GUI runs exe file async couple times and when they are being started I should attach those processes to my GUI?:D They close immediately, so should I do something as `Thread.Sleep(10000);` in my workers?

Comment: was just typing an answer for that case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give much info about the interaction between the gui and the worker, but if attaching to the process is too hard (typically beacuse the worker only runs briefly), a more usable scenario is to add a configuration option to the gui to add an extra argument to the worker command line, on which the worker responds with a DebugBreak. For example the worker's main would be

```
var args = ParseArguments(); //check if string 'WaitForDeugger' is on command line
if( args.RequestsDebug )
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

....
```

And the gui invokes the worker like this:

```
var args = GetArgumentsForWorker();
if( someSpecialDebugOptionEnabled )
  args += " WaitForDeugger";
Process.Start( "worker.exe", args );
```